# WordPress post update AFTER ACF field updates

Tags: wordpress, transition, advanced-custom-fields, status, acfpro

The code below sends out an email every time I (change the STATUS field and then) safe/update the post. But it's not working the way I want and I know whats's wrong:

The field updates are always saved AFTER the post is saved so it always sends out the PREVIOUS field values (its like I'm always 1 step behind).

How can I let the POST UPDATE come LAST so that the then triggered action (send email) will have the latest field values included?

```
function yl_send_booking_email_after_post_update( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if ( $new_status == $old_status ) {

        if ( 'booking' === get_post_type() ) { // check the custom post type

            $send_email = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_send_email', true );

            if ( $send_email === 'yes' ) {

                $status = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_status', true );

                if ( $status === 'confirmed' ) {
                    $subject = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email_title_confirmed', true );            
                } else if ( $status === 'changed' ) {
                    $subject = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email_title_changed', true );
                } else if ( $status === 'canceled by guest' ) {
                    $subject = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email_title_canceled_by_guest', true );
                } else {
                    $subject = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email_title_canceled_by_us', true );
                }

                if ( $status === 'confirmed' ) {
                    $body = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email_content_confirmed', true );         
                } else if ( $status === 'changed' ) {
                    $body = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email_content_changed', true );
                } else if ( $status === 'canceled by guest' ) {
                    $body = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email_content_canceled_by_guest', true );
                } else {
                    $body = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email_content_canceled_by_us', true );
                }

                $to = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bookings_field_email', true );

                $headers = array
                    (
                    'From: ' . get_bloginfo('name') . ' <' . get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>',
                    'Bcc: ' . get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(),
                    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
                    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
                    );
                $headers = implode( "\r\n" , $headers );

                wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

            }

        }

    }

}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'yl_send_booking_email_after_post_update', 15, 3 );
```

**UPDATE:**
After getting some info from the ACF team I had to change my code. See below. I get NO errors but there's NO email being send... Any ideas?

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'yl_send_booking_email_after_post_update', 5 );
function yl_send_booking_email_after_post_update( $post_id ) {

    if ( 'booking' === get_post_type() ) { // check the custom post type

        // Get submitted values.
        $values = $_POST['acf'];

        // Check if a specific value was updated.
        if( isset($_POST['acf']['bookings_field_status']) ) {

            $send_email = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_send_email'];

            if ( $send_email === 'yes' ) {

                $status = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_status'];

                if ( $status === 'confirmed' ) {
                    $subject = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email_subject_confirmed'];
                } elseif ( $status === 'changed' ) {
                    $subject = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email_subject_changed'];
                } elseif ( $status === 'canceled by guest' ) {
                    $subject = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email_subject_canceled_by_guest'];
                } else {
                    $subject = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email_subject_canceled_by_us'];
                }

                if ( $status === 'confirmed' ) {
                    $subject = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email_body_confirmed'];
                } elseif ( $status === 'changed' ) {
                    $subject = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email_body_changed'];
                } elseif ( $status === 'canceled by guest' ) {
                    $subject = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email_body_canceled_by_guest'];
                } else {
                    $subject = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email_body_canceled_by_us'];
                }

                $to = $_POST['acf']['bookings_field_email'];

                $headers = array
                    (
                    'From: ' . get_bloginfo('name') . ' <' . get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>',
                    'Bcc: ' . get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(),
                    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
                    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
                );
                $headers = implode( "\r\n" , $headers );

                wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete working code (for those who like to use):

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'yl_send_booking_email_after_status_update', 5);
function yl_send_booking_email_after_status_update( $post_id ) {

    // Get submitted values.
    $values = $_POST['acf'];

    // Check if a specific value was updated.
    if ( isset($_POST['acf']['field_5ed8117407663']) ) {

        $booking_status = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed8117407663'];
        $send_email     = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed81174076ac'];

        if ( $send_email == 'yes' ) {

            $to = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed41758ed4b5'];

            if ( $booking_status == 'confirmed' ) {
                $subject = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed81174076f2'];
                $message = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed8117407741'];
            } elseif ( $booking_status == 'changed' ) {
                $subject = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed8117407788'];
                $message = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed81174077df'];
            } elseif ( $booking_status == 'canceled by guest' ) {
                $subject = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed8117407829'];
                $message = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed8117407870'];
            } else {
                $subject = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed81174078b7'];
                $message = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed81174078fd'];
            }

            $headers = array
                (
                'From: ' . get_bloginfo('name') . ' <' . get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>',
                'Bcc: ' . get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(),
                'MIME-Version: 1.0',
                'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
            );
            $headers = implode( "\r\n" , $headers );

            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2**
Got it working. Code below:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'yl_send_booking_email_after_status_update', 5);
function yl_send_booking_email_after_status_update( $post_id ) {

    // Get submitted values.
    $values = $_POST['acf'];

    // Check if a specific value was updated.
    if( isset($_POST['acf']['field_5ed8117407663']) ) {

        $to         = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed41758ed4b5'];
        $subject    = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed81174076f2'];
        $message    = $_POST['acf']['field_5ed8117407741'];

        $headers = array
            (
            'From: ' . get_bloginfo('name') . ' <' . get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>',
            'Bcc: ' . get_bloginfo('admin_email'),
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(),
            'MIME-Version: 1.0',
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
        );
        $headers = implode( "\r\n" , $headers );

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

    }
}
```